# How can i combine sub_category in same list only if parent title is same?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Any idea to check that list is already created or not? Or any filter method that i can get mentioned response?

i am getting this type of response.

```
[
{
    "Politics": [
        "Government"
    ]
},
{
    "Politics": [
        "Court"
    ]
},
{
    "State News": [
        "State 1"
    ]
},
{
    "State News": [
        "State 2"
    ]
}
```

]

here is my views.py

```
class getCategoriesAPIView(APIView):
def get(self, request):
    queryset = SubCategory.objects.filter()
    toList = []
    for items in queryset:
        toDict = {}
        toDict1 = {}
        toDict[items.category.title] = []
        toDict1['sub_category'] = items.sub_title
        toDict[items.category.title].append(toDict1['sub_category'])
        toList.append(toDict)
    return JsonResponse(toList, safe=False)
```

I need response like this:

```
[
{
    "Politics": [
        "Government",
        "Court"
    ]
}
{
    "State News": [
        "State 1"
        "State 2"
    ]
}
```

]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is also an option:

```
lst = [{"Politics": ["Government"]}, {"Politics": ["Court"]},
       {"State News": ["State 1"]}, {"State News": ["State 2"]}]

d = defaultdict(list)
for elem in lst:
    for k, v in elem.items():
        d[k].extend(v)

new_lst = [{k: v} for k, v in d.items()]
print(new_lst)
```

```
[{'Politics': ['Government', 'Court']}, {'State News': ['State 1', 'State 2']}]
```

---

```
def get(self, request):
    queryset = SubCategory.objects.filter()

    items_per_category = defaultdict(list)
    for items in queryset:
        items_per_category[items.category.title].extend(items.sub_title)
    data = [{k: v} for k, v in items_per_category.items()]
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that:

```py
def get(self, request):
    queryset = SubCategory.objects.filter()
    items_per_category = {}
    for items in queryset:
        category_title = items.category.title
        existing_items = items_per_category.get(category_title, [])
        existing_items.append(items.sub_title)
        items_per_category[category_title] = existing_items
    data = [{k: v} for k, v in items_per_category.items()]
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Basically, we first build a dictionnary that looks like `{category1: [subtitle1, subtitle2, ...], category2: [...]}` and then we reshape it into a list of dict with 1 key each time